# Github Pages with single custom subdomain for multiple repositories (using paths)

Tags: github, github-pages

I have multiple Github Repositories. By all of them `gh-pages` are enabled, and the repositories are accessible via paths for example:

- `username.github.io/repository1`,
- `username.github.io/repository2`,
- `...`

Now I'm trying to create a custom subdomain `docs.foo.tld` and to have all my repositories `gh-pages` to be accessible via

- `docs.foo.tld/repository1`
- `docs.foo.tld/repository2`
- `...`

I have created a `CNAME` entry `docs.foo.tld` to `username.github.io`

But when I'm adding this custom domain (`docs.foo.tld`) in `repository1` repository settings on github, the `gh-pages` are directly accessible via `docs.foo.tld`, not via `docs.foo.tld/repository1`

How I use all this repositories in the path segments `/repository1`, `/repository2` when using same custom subdomain for all of them.

> Also to note, when I try to add this custom subdomain to `repository2`, I get the exception as the `CNAME` is already taken.

Comment: Strange, for me this just works, though I do get those warning emails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CNAME and setting the custom domain should only be done in the .github.io repo.

Other repos should not contain a `CNAME` and you should not set the custom domain in the other repositories. Those settings are inherited from .github.io repo and setting them in the other repositories is overwriting the root site.

Just delete the `CNAME` records from the project repos, and remove the custom domain from the settings of the project repos. You may need to add the custom domain name back to the .github.io repo, but after that you should be all setup like you wish.

Comment: Which one is the ".github.io" repo? Is this any of projects repositiories, e.g. `project1`. Or should this be some other separate repository. With some specific repository name, or content inside?

Comment: Indeed, I have create a repositiory with the name `foo.github.io` in our organization `foo`, activated pages with CNAME `docs.foo.tld`, and now all the repositories are accessible via `docs.foo.tld/repository1`, `...`. Thanks

Comment: This answer is correct. However, it's pretty hard to recognize it as such until you end up with the solution. My answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/70642229/707984 tells basically the same, with more details and pictures.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, but with the root account being an Organisation, not a User site (but this makes no difference). The solution is surprisingly simple (I had many trials and errors):

1. If not yet done, create the special Organisation/User "umbrella" Site [as per the doc](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites) by creating a git repository called `myorg.github.io`.
2. In the Settings of that repo, under the "Pages" tab, choose your custom domain `docs.mydomain.com`. See picture:

[image: Pages Settings of the umbrella Organisation Site]

3. The content of this repo is up to you. Personally I use [VitePress](http://vitepress.vuejs.org/) with a small script which deploys at the **root** of the `gh-pages` branch. The script includes the creation of a `CNAME` file at the project root, with the content `docs.mydomain.com'
4. Configure your DNS zone with your Internet Provider by adding a `CNAME` entry pointing to `myorg.github.io.` (note the trailing dot – your IP may or may not add it automatically for you).
5. Return to the Pages Settings of your GitHub umbrella repo, and check that the subdomain is validated (it may take a few minutes).

That's all for the umbrella docs site, whose content contains links to `docs.mydomain.com/project1`, `docs.mydomain.com/project2` etc.

Now, here is the trick: there is no trick. In all of your real projects, simply deploy your documentation. You can do so in the `docs` subfolder or not, in either branch, that is, in the `master` or `gh-pages` one, it doesn't seem to matter.

If any, the `docs/` part of the url will be replaced by `project1/` etc. There is no need for a CNAME, and no need for another custom subdomain.

Here is the config of one my project:

[image: Pages Settings of one my project]

See how GitHub indicates under which URL the site is published.

Here is my [GitHub organisation](https://github.com/arcsecond-io/) and its [umbrella site](https://github.com/arcsecond-io/arcsecond-io.github.io)

and the results:

- https://docs.arcsecond.io
- https://docs.arcsecond.io/cli
- https://docs.arcsecond.io/oort

**Bonus**. If by any chance you configure your projects to have sub-subdomains (that's what I tried before finding the solution) – such as `https://project1.docs.mydomain.com`, the above configuration will also "work". That is, navigating to `https://docs.mydomain.com/project1`  will redirect you to `https://project1.docs.mydomain.com`

Internet is kind of amazing, isn't it?

Comment: It is worth noting that this works for PUBLIC GitHub Pages. Seems it doesn't work for PRIVATE GitHub Pages at this time (June 2023). Each private GitHub Page can have a custom domain, but you can't have this nice generic approach with private pages (hope they change / fix soon)!

Comment: Correct. In that context, given the documentation I produce is going public, it makes sense to have documentation-only public repos. But for mixed repos, if you don't want to expose everything, this wouldn't work.